# AsyncRetryPolicy (with wait) not retry the delegate when handling exception thrown from the action (works fine for the AsyncRetry without wait)

Tags: c#, polly

I am using Polly 7.1.0 in my Xamarin mobile solution for the REST API call. As it is a mobile app, the key problem for us is to retry a few times when the network connection exceptions (HttpRequestException, WebException, etc...) occurs.

Basically, for most of the service calls, I am applying a policy wrap with Fallback -> Timeout -> RetryAndWait policies.  The most inner policy will do the retry with wait when HttpRequestException/WebException etc happens, then Timeout policy for the total time for the retries, and then the outer fallback policy to get a failure return with error message depends on the Exception type.

But when I do the test with the internet disconnected, only a few of the API calls work as expected, most of other will not execute the retry policy (just timeout and then fallback).

If I put **try-catch (with throw)** statement in the **HandleRequestAsync** method of the base class, **HttpRequestException** was thrown, technically the retry policy should handle the exception and execute the action again, but for some reason, it doesn't work as I expected.

***If I use retry (instead of retry and wait) for the inner policy, it does retry as expected.***

A few major classes:

1. PolicyHelper (to get the policies)

```
    public static class PolicyHelper
    {
        public static AsyncFallbackPolicy<TResponse> GetFallbackPolicy<TResponse>(TResponse fallbackValue,
                                                                                  Action<Exception, IDictionary<string,string>>  fallbackHandler = null,
                                                                                  bool showAlert = true)                                                
        {
            return Policy<TResponse>.Handle<WebException>()
                                    .Or<HttpRequestException>()
                                    .Or<TaskCanceledException>()
                                    .Or<TimeoutRejectedException>()
                                    .Or<Exception>(IsAndroidHttpClientException)
                                    .FallbackAsync
                                    (
                                        fallbackAction : (context, ct) =>
                                        {
                                            return Task.FromResult(fallbackValue);
                                        },
                                        onFallbackAsync : async (result, context) =>
                                        {
                                            Exception exception = result?.Exception ?? new APIServiceException("API call failed.");
                                            if (fallbackHandler != null)
                                            {
                                                IDictionary<string, string> properties = null;
                                                if (context != null)
                                                {
                                                    properties = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                                                    if (context.TryGetValue("CallerMethod", out object callMethod) && callMethod != null)
                                                        properties.Add("CallerMethod", callMethod.ToString());

                                                    if (context.TryGetValue("EndPoint", out object endpoint) && endpoint != null)
                                                        properties.Add("EndPoint", endpoint.ToString());
                                                }

                                                fallbackHandler.Invoke(exception, properties);
                                            }

                                            //Always to dismiss the possible loading 
                                            UserDialogs.Instance.HideLoading();

                                            //Manipulate the err message according to the exception type.
                                            if (fallbackValue != null && typeof(UbiApiResonse).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(TResponse)))
                                            {
                                                if (exception is TimeoutRejectedException)
                                                    (fallbackValue as UbiApiResonse).ErrMsg = GlobalConfig.TimeoutErrorMessage;
                                                else if (exception is WebException ||
                                                        (exception.InnerException != null && exception.InnerException is WebException) ||
                                                         IsAndroidHttpClientException(exception))
                                                    (fallbackValue as UbiApiResonse).ErrMsg = GlobalConfig.NetworkErrorMessage;
                                                if (showAlert)
                                                    UserDialogs.Instance.Alert((fallbackValue as UbiApiResonse).ErrMsg);
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                if (showAlert)
                                                    UserDialogs.Instance.Alert(GlobalConfig.GeneralErrorMessage);
                                            }

                                            await Task.FromResult(true);                                            
                                        }
                                    );
        }


        public static AsyncTimeoutPolicy<TResponse> GetTimeoutPolicy<TResponse>(int timeoutInMilliSecs)
        {
            return Policy.TimeoutAsync<TResponse>(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutInMilliSecs));
        }


        public static AsyncRetryPolicy<TResponse> GetWaitAndRetryPolicy<TResponse>(int maxRetryCount, TimeSpan retryInterval)
        {
            return Policy<TResponse>.Handle<WebException>()
                                     .Or<HttpRequestException>()
                                     .Or<TaskCanceledException>()
                                     .Or<TimeoutRejectedException>()
                                     .Or<Exception>(IsAndroidHttpClientException)
                                     .WaitAndRetryAsync
                                     (
                                        maxRetryCount,
                                        retryAttempt => retryInterval
                                     );
        }


        public static AsyncRetryPolicy<TResponse> GetRetryPolicy<TResponse>(int maxRetryCount)
        {
            return Policy<TResponse>.Handle<WebException>()
                                     .Or<HttpRequestException>()
                                     .Or<TaskCanceledException>()
                                     .Or<TimeoutRejectedException>()
                                     .Or<Exception>(IsAndroidHttpClientException)
                                     .RetryAsync
                                     (
                                        maxRetryCount
                                     );
        }

        //As Xamarin.Android http request handler only throw java excepotion
        //we need catch all Excetpion by check the type name with string comparison
        private static bool IsAndroidHttpClientException(Exception exception)
        {
            string exceptionTypeName = exception.GetType().FullName.ToLower();

            return exceptionTypeName.Contains("javax.net.ssl.sslexception") ||
                   exceptionTypeName.Contains("java.net.socketexception") ||
                   exceptionTypeName.Contains("java.net.unknownhostexception") ||
                   exceptionTypeName.Contains("java.io.ioexception") ||
                   exceptionTypeName.Contains("java.lang.exception");
        }
    }
```

2. APIBaseService (the base class of all the service class. this class has the actual policy executions for the service methods)

```
    public abstract class APIBaseService
    {
        private static HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();
        private object _httpClientLocker = new object();
        //private int _tryCounter;
        protected APIBaseService()
        {
        }

        protected async Task<TResponse> HandleRequestWithPolicyAndFallbackAsync<TResponse>(string endPoint,
                                                                                object payload = null,
                                                                                AsyncPolicy<TResponse> asyncPolicy = null,
                                                                                bool showAlert = false,
                                                                                [CallerMemberName] string callerMethod = null) where TResponse : new()
        {
            var fallbackValue = GetFallbackValue<TResponse>();
            var fallbackPolicy = PolicyHelper.GetFallbackPolicy<TResponse>(fallbackValue, HandleExceptionAfterPolicy, showAlert);

            //default inner policy
            if (asyncPolicy == null)
            {
                asyncPolicy = Policy.WrapAsync<TResponse>(PolicyHelper.GetTimeoutPolicy<TResponse>(5000),
                                                          PolicyHelper.GetWaitAndRetryPolicy<TResponse>(3, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(100)));
            }

            //Wrap fallback and inner policy
            var policyWrap = Policy.WrapAsync<TResponse>(fallbackPolicy, asyncPolicy);

            try
            {
                return await DoRequestWithPolicy(endPoint, payload, policyWrap, callerMethod);
            }
            //ideally other exception type should be caught by 
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                IDictionary<string, string> properties = GetCallerMetaData(endPoint, callerMethod);

                HandleExceptionAfterPolicy(ex, properties);
                return GetFallbackValue<TResponse>(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private async Task<TResponse> DoRequestWithPolicy<TResponse>(string endPoint,
                                                                     object payload,
                                                                     AsyncPolicy<TResponse> asyncPolicy,
                                                                     string callerMethod)
        {
            //_tryCounter = 0;
            Context context = new Context("HandleRequest", new Dictionary<string, object>());
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(callerMethod))
                context.Add("CallerMethod", callerMethod);
            context.Add("EndPoint", endPoint);

            using (CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource())
            {
                TResponse response = await asyncPolicy.ExecuteAsync(async (ctx, ct) =>
                {
                    return await HandleRequestAsync<TResponse>(endPoint, payload, ct);
                }, context, cts.Token);

                return response;
            }
        }

        private async Task<TResponse> HandleRequestAsync<TResponse>(string endPoint, object payload, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            HttpClientSetup();
            using (var httpContent = CreateHttpContent(payload))
            {

                using (var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync(endPoint, httpContent, cancellationToken))
                using (var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
                {
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                        return DeserializeJsonFromStream<TResponse>(stream);

                    //Ideally, here should throw an exception.
                    //To keep backwards compatibility, we just return a failure response or a value for model
                    var errorDetails = await StreamToStringAsync(stream);
                    return GetFallbackValue<TResponse>(errorDetails);
                 }
            }
        }
```

3. The service classes
   The below service method works fine as expected (ie when network is disconnected, it will retry 3 times for the HttpRequestException and then return a fallback value with the proper error message)

```
public class SearchAPIService : APIBaseService, ISearchAPIService
{
    public async Task<SearchResponse> SearchAsync(double latitude, double longitude, DateTime timeIn, DateTime timeOut, BoundsModel bounds, FilterModel filter)
    {
        var endPoint = AppConstants.BaseURL + GlobalConfig.APIVersion + "/search";

        var request = new SearchRequest
        {
            Location = new LatLngModel(latitude, longitude),
            Filter = filter,
            Bounds = bounds,
            ArrivalTime = timeIn,
            DepartureTime = timeOut,
        };

        var asyncPolicy = Policy.WrapAsync(PolicyHelper.GetTimeoutPolicy<SearchResponse>(10000),
                                            PolicyHelper.GetWaitAndRetryPolicy<SearchResponse>(3, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500)));

        return await HandleRequestWithPolicyAndFallbackAsync(endPoint, request, asyncPolicy, true);
        }
    }
```

**However, another service which has exactly policy applied will never do the retry and JUST get timeout by the outer Timeout policy**

If I put try-catch (with throw) statement in the **HandleRequestAsync** method of the base class, HttpRequestException was thrown, technically the retry policy should handle the exception and execute the action again, but for some reason, it doesn't work as I expected.

***If I use retry (instead of retry and wait) for the inner policy, it does retry as expected.***

Not sure if I did anything wrong.

```
public class PaymentAPIService : APIBaseService, IPaymentAPIService
{
    public async Task<PayStatusResponse> PayStatusAsync()

    {
        var endPoint = AppConstants.BaseURL + GlobalConfig.APIVersion + "/pay/status";
        var asyncPolicy = Policy.WrapAsync(PolicyHelper.GetTimeoutPolicy<PayStatusResponse>(3500),
                                            PolicyHelper.GetWaitAndRetryPolicy<PayStatusResponse>(3, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(100)));
        return await HandleRequestWithPolicyAndFallbackAsync<PayStatusResponse>(endPoint, null, asyncPolicy, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is possible that you are seeing the timeout on the inner `HttpClient` occurring before the retries have time to complete.  See for example this discussion here: https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/issues/512#issuecomment-427472108

Comment: @mountaintraveller, Thanks for your response. Understood the case you mentioned, but I don't think that is the case for me. I ended up to have the wait inside the retry by Task.Delay inside the "onRetryAsync". 
` .RetryAsync(3, 
                onRetryAsync: async (result, retry) => 
                                 {
                                     await Task.Delay(500)
                                 });
`
 Not sure if this a good way. And I still suspect there was something wrong for my code to apply the policy which cased the retry and wait did not work.

Comment: Understood. If further investigation was wanted, we would really need a [reproducible (runnable) example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  A difference between your workround and how the policy waits is that the policy's wait (and whether to retry) honours cancellation (including timing-out cancellation), which could suggest that cancellation or time-out was implicated. In general the policies have 000s users, so I am not suspecting a policy fault (tho happy to be shown wrong).